# Can I use whatever method GRUB uses to interact with keyboard inside the main system?

Tags: drivers, grub, keyboard

This question is effectively a follow-up to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1506951/laptop-keyboard-not-working-when-trying-to-install-ubuntu-23-10) (to which I haven't got a satisfactory answer, also look there for the list of things I tried to fix the keyboard problem).

My new laptop has a huge problem with keyboard drivers: basically when running on Ubuntu it does not detect its own built-in keyboard not matter what I do, but the Bluetooth external keyboard is working just fine. The built-in keyboard also works in BIOS and in the GRUB menu.

The way I understand it, GRUB is basically a component of Ubuntu. So, can I make Ubuntu use whatever method GRUB uses to interact with the keyboard?

Comment: "grub is basically a component of Ubuntu" ... about as much as a ferry carrying a truck across a river is part of the truck. The truck needs it to cross the river, but otherwise doesn't need it to actually run (and it could use other methods to cross the river, just like Ubuntu can use other ways to boot than GRUB).

Comment: are you positively sure it's a bluetooth keyboard, and not another wireless keyboard, or some hybrid thing? (For example, I had a logitech keyboard with both bluetooth and proprietary wireless links, and the bluetooth was awesome because it worked with every laptop, phone and TV out of the box, and the proprietary link was used when there was no bluetooth connectivity, but needed a specific dongle, IF I REMEMBER CORRECTLY)

Comment: I am positively sure the __external__ keyboard that works correctly is a Bluetooth keyboard: it is called "Bluetooth 3.0 keyboard", is connected through the Bluetooth menu, has a Bluetooth sign painted on it and was originally used to connect to an Android tablet.

Comment: "No matter what I do" makes it difficult to determine if a solution has been tried. So, did you look at blacklisting intel_vbtn Kernel? Did you uncheck “Slow Keys” in Accessibility Settings? Does the keyboard work in recovery-mode?

Comment: Almost all the things I did are listed in the linked post. Yes, I did all of the proposed things. I am not positively sure what exactly is meant by "the recovery mode", it does not work in the "safe graphics" mode.

Comment: @DaigakunoBaku the thing is that while it's thoroughly possible that has been implemented, I've not yet worked on a machine whose UEFI setup had a bluetooth stack, but I've met many mislabeled electronics (including things that said one wireless standard on top, but did something completely different). The funny thing is that bluetooth pairing would have to be done between the firmware of your computer then and your keyboard, and again for your main OS and your keyboard, as far as I understand bluetooth encryption keys.

Comment: Maybe, but what does it have to do with grub interacting with keyboard or with the built-in keyboard not being detected?

Comment: I think something in your system is emulating a plain USB keyboard instead of a bluetooth one. And as soon as bluetooth in your system comes up, that breaks. However, can't diagnose that without knowing specifics. Asking to help, you know, not trying to annoy you :)

Comment: I had this problem way before I connected the Bluetooth keyboard, right from the Live Boot USB menu. I can share the specifics you need if you still think the problem may be here

Comment: Lots of off topic discussion. Grub uses UEFI/BIOS drivers, so not related to Ubuntu's drivers. What brand/model system? What video card/chip. Have you updated UEFI firmware (and SSD if you have that). You may just need a boot parameter or install of something specific for your system.